# Buttons location in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I added buttons to my SVG in D3, attached the link from where I take the code:
https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_button_data_simple.html

the Default of this code is to locate the buttons in the left top corner of the svg.
How can I change the buttons location on my svg?
Bonus question - How can I change the color or style of my buttons?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you shared, the buttons are not part of the SVG. they appear about it and not part to the  tag.

There are 2 options IMO:

1. You can still put the buttons outside of the svg and give them CSS `position: absolute` and change `top` & `right` properties to change their location.
2. You can move the buttons inside the svg element using `<forigenObject>` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), and give him CSS property `transform: translate(X px,Y px)`.

Comment: How can I do it, Example code please